# Changing font color of an element in wordpress theme

Tags: css, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am new to Wordpress and CSS. I have recently purchased a wordpress [theme](http://themeforest.net/item/vernumresponsive-onepage-parallax-wordpress-theme/4843905)

I have created a [website](http://www.emergingmiddleclass.com/) and I want to change the color of some elements in the website. So for instance, under the menu item "The Opportunity", there is a picture that says "Potential of the EMC customer" The line under that is in grey and is barely readable.

So I want to change the color. The theme Options allow me to use custom CSS..

[image]

The code I am using is:

```
media="all"
.white-overlay p {
padding: 5px 0 15px;
font-size: 15px;
color: #a81800;
}
```

When I try to add the code to stle.css under wp-content/themes/vernum (I am accessing this file using FTP), I see this:

/*
Theme Name: Vernum - Responsive One Page Parallax Template
Theme URI: http://spyropress.com/themes/vernum
Author: Spyropress
Author URI: http://spyropress.com/
Description: Vernum is a project of the spring, joyful one page website. It is modern and clean, very easy to edit. It's prepared to use with jquery parallax efect. There are flat and simple graphics. It's multipurpose, so you can use it as portfolio, or personal page, whatever you want …
Version: 1.8.2
License: WordPress theme is comprised of two parts: (1) The PHP code is licensed under the GPL license as is WordPress itself.  You will find a copy of the license text in the same directory as this text file. Or you can read it here: http://codex.wordpress.org/GPL (2) All other parts of the theme including, but not limited to the CSS code, images, and design are licensed according to the license purchased. Read about licensing details here:

```
http://wiki.envato.com/support/legal-terms/licensing-terms/
License URI: license.txt
Tags: agency, clean, easy to use, flat, minimal, modern, multipurpose, one page, parallax, portfolio, responsive, retina, simple, spring, spyropress, builder
Text Domain: spyropress
*/


.wp-caption { }
.wp-caption-text { }
.sticky { }
.gallery-caption { }
.bypostauthor { }
.alignright { }
.aligncenter { }
.alignleft { }
```

So I am not sure where exactly should I add the code
But it does not change the color! Would anyone help e investigate..I've been struggling with it for hours :(

Comment: Just delete media="all" part (first line of your custom css) and it should work.

Comment: Why have you got `media="all"` in there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need `media="all"` here, so just remove it:

```
.white-overlay p {
    padding: 5px 0 15px;
    font-size: 15px;
    color: #a81800;
}
```

Comment: Hi I tried adding this code to the window shown in the sceenshot..but it does not alter anything. I dont know if it's a wordpress theme issue

Comment: @bob_d Try to add your code directly inside `style.css` file of your theme, not through the admin panel like what you're doing at this moment

Comment: do you know where is the style.css file located in wordpress. As I mentioned I am quite new to the environment

Comment: @bob_d You can go inside `wp-content/themes/your-theme-name/style.css`

Comment: Please refer to my updated question to see the problem I am facing in changing style.css

Comment: @bob_d Just add at the end of your file

Comment: when i add it at the end of style.css and save it, i dont see any change

Comment: I see a couple of other css files such as font.css etc..should i add it there

Comment: @bob_d Navigate to this file `http://www.emergingmiddleclass.com/wp-content/themes/vernum/vernum/assets/css/layout.css?ver=3.8.1` and add your code inside `.white-overlay`

Comment: i really appreciate your help a lot! I looked in the directory and found the file loayout.css but not layout.css?ver=3.8.1. I made the changes and saved it, then went back ti my page to inspect element but saw no change in the css of the element i have been wanting to change..so strange!! :(

Answer (score 0):

If all you want to do is change the colour of the text underneath then just insert the following in your custom css:

```
.white-overlay p {
    color: #a81800;
}
```

This will leave all the other properties (font size and padding) as they were originally specified in the main CSS file. You shouldn't put media="all" in the CSS because:

- It's redundant; the browser will assume that a rule applies to all media types unless told otherwise.
- The syntax is actually formatted like this:

  @media [media type] { [selector] { [property]: [value]; }

If you wanted to make the transparent overlay a little less transparent you could also add the following code:

```
.white-overlay {
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6);
}
```

The final number in the *background* value specifies the opacity (from 0 to 1) and has been changed by me from 0.5 to 0.6.

Comment: I'm not sure why even after adding this code to my browser, it does not change the display

Comment: I'd suggest that you simply add it to your custom CSS file. You can always take it out or tweak it if you're not happy with the results.

Answer (score -1):

I have experienced the same problem with the Vernum Wordpress theme. For some reason (which I cannot understand) they style.css is not 'correctly' linked.
I solved the issue by adding a copy of the header.php of the parent theme inside the child theme folder, and adding the following line:

```
<head>
    <?php wp_head(); ?>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo get_stylesheet_uri(); ?>" type="text/css"     media="screen" />

</head>
```

This seems to give correct visibility to the style.css, so that it can be overridden by the child theme.
Note that I am currently experiencing other problems with the Vernum theme, concerning the use of multiple stylesheet, so it seems to be not the ideal theme to try and re-style.

good luck
Giovanni